# Why does adding "const" solve "invalid operands to binary expression"

Tags: c++, constants, overloading

I have overloaded the operator + by `Integer operator+(Integer & a, Integer & b)`. But when I do *a=b+c+d*, it gives the error of *invalid operands to binary expression*. But by adding `const` to the parameters, no more errors. Why this happens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`b + c + d` generates a temporary for the result of `b + c`. A reference to that temporary is then passed to the second call to `operator+`().

Only `const` references can be bound to temporaries.

For further discussion, see [How come a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object)